# What would the surface of a Jupiter brain look like?

Tags: science-based, artificial-intelligence, megastructures

> A Jupiter brain is a computational substrate comparable in mass and size to a gas giant planet, typically in the 1X10^27 kilogram range.

Could you live on it, if it had atmosphere, or would the surface gravity, temperature or radiation be too high? Would it even have a surface, or is a Jupiter brain gaseous with a blazing molten core like the planet from which it derives its name?

Comment: What is a "Jupiter Brain"?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrioshka_brain

Comment: **edit the question** rather than relying on comments to make it understandable.  In any case, Matroshka refers to layering and is used in conjuction with nested dyson shells, not jupiter-mass planets.

Comment: Yes but the wiki article does talk about Jupiter brains as well.

Comment: Suggest you drill down through the references and look up the sources dealing with Jupiter brains. There's some good crunchy stuff hidden there. It might help answer your question too.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the outside surface of such a structure would be composed of extensive heat sinks to radiate heat away so that the temperature of the computational systems could be maintained at optimal levels.

Additionally, the overall structure of this "brain" would more likely to be a swarm of satellites rather than a solid structure.

Comment: Well, the intelligence (that is to say the brain) has reasons for constructing its body so that it is habitable (i.e. has a solid surface, possibly with subterranean caverns and caves containing different atmospheres and surface gravities for different species). Would it still be able to function as a solid mass? How much efficiency would it lose?

Comment: @Z.Schroeder An object the size of Jupiter couldn't exist as a solid mass - too much matter, it would collapse under its own weight.

Comment: @Z.Schroeder The swarm of satellites could easily contain individual habitats that each had their own atmospheres and rates of rotation for custom levels of "gravity".  If all of your habitats were linked together, separate levels of "gravity" would not be possible.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you ar e getting at or not Michael, and I may be wrong, but I think that many satellites would just collapse together and form a normal planet covered in in a lithosphere of "satellites".

Comment: @Marie only if they were slowing and colliding.  If they collided, you'd have some fragments flying off to lower orbits.  Et c.

Comment: @can-ned_food I meant that if you had a planet-sized ball of satellites there would likely be a lot of gravity and pressure involved that would pull them all together regardless of their attempts to maintain "orbit" wouldnt there? Similar to [this XKCD](https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/)

Comment: @Marie depends on the mass, the density.  if there was friction or other losses which degraded their orbits …  of course, we are not necessarily holding ourselves to the mass and size requirements of a planet like Jupiter, though the little nodes in this swarm of orbits would have a different distribution profile of mass than would Jupiter.